# CodeIgniter Nothing happens database

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Hi I am following a turtorial to learn CodeIgniter on [NetTuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-2/).

I have one model, one view and one controller involved.

The Model:

```
class Data_model extends CI_Model{
  function getAll(){
      $data = array();

      $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM data");
      if($q->num_row() > 0){
           foreach($q->result() as $row){
                $data[] = $row;
           }
           return $data;
      }
 }
```

}

The View:

```
<html>
 <head>
      <title></title>
 </head>

 <body>
      <p>View loaded</p>
      <?php 
           foreach ($rows as $r){
                echo '<h1>',$r->title,'</h1>';
           }
      ?>
 </body>
```

The Controller:

```
class Site extends CI_Controller {

 function index(){
      $this->load->model('data_model');
      $data['rows'] = $this->data_model->getAll();

      $this->load->view('home');
 }
}
```

The problem is that I don't get an error but just an empty page. What am I doing wrong? It feels like I am doing everything from the tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does work:

```
class Data_model extends CI_Model{

 function getAll(){
 $data = array();
 $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM data");


   $data= $q->result(); //result_array() will fetch as arrays and not objects
   return $data;


 }
}
```

But this dosn't:

```
class Data_model extends CI_Model{
 function getAll(){
 $data = array();
 $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM data");

 if($q->num_row() > 0){
   $data= $q->result(); //result_array() will fetch as arrays and not objects
   return $data;
}

 }
}
```

But why is this the case, and is this even correct to do (is this even an answer), what consequences could be meet by removing this IF statement?

Comment: Made a silly mistake here `if($q->num_row() > 0){` will be `if($q->num_rows() > 0){`. Mind the `s` in `num_rows()`. :D

Answer (score 5):

In controller:

```
$this->load->view('home', $data);
```

Suggestion for model:

```
function getAll(){
    $data = array();
    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM data");
    if($q->num_row() > 0){
       $data    = $q->result(); //result_array() will fetch as arrays and not objects
       return $data;
    }
}
```

Try this one as it is already given by `Paul`:

```
echo '<h1>' . $r->title . '</h1>';
```

Go to your root/index.php and change `environment` to `developing` to see the error generated by php.

Comment: Made a silly mistake here `if($q->num_row() > 0){` will be `if($q->num_rows() > 0){`. Mind the `s` in `num_rows()`. :D

Answer (score 3):

In the model,

```
$q->num_row()
```

needs to be changed to

```
$q->num_rows()
```

Also, you need to reference the specific column too

```
$data[] = $row->column_name;
```

In your controller, the commas need to be replaced with periods. Commas aren't proper syntax

```
foreach ($rows as $r) {
    echo '<h1>'.$r->title.'</h1>';
}
```

Finally, you need to pass the $data variable to the view by doing

```
$this->load->view('home', $data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, I think in your View you have to make this changes:

```
echo '<h1>' . $r->title . '</h1>';
```